# Different from + the same as

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, clauses, structure

I am often confused about the following usage of these phrases. Please consider the following:

> 1. I do a different thing from you
> 2. I do a different thing from you do
> 3. I do a different thing from what you do
> 4. I do a different thing from yours
> 5. I have the same car as you
> 6. I have the same car as you do
> 7. I have the same car as yours
> 8. I have the same car as what you have

Which ones are ungrammatical and, if you will, what is the sense of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1 is acceptable, but would in my view be improved by using "than" instead of "from".
- 2 is not acceptable as written. It wpould be OK as "I do a different thing than you do."
- 3 is at least non-standard, if not wrong. "from what you do" is not used in standard English. again a use of "than" fixes this: "I do a different thing than what you do" is ok if a bit stilted.
- 4 is at least odd, if not wrong. Again, using "than" in place of "from" improves this.

> - I do a different thing than you
> - I do a different thing than you do
> - I do a different thing than what you do
> - I do a different thing than yours

All of these mean "The thing I do is different from the thing you do."

5, 6, and 7 are all acceptable, and the all mean

> The car [that] I have is the same as the car that you have.

8 is not ok, the sequence "what you have" is not used in this construction. If "what" is replaced by "the one" this becomes acceptable, with the same meaning as the previous three.

Comment: Well, thank you. But, about this "than", can't we use "from" as the preposition for "different"?